# How to apply stop words at Solr query time?

Tags: content-search, solr

I'm having some fun with Solr and here is my current issue.

I've applied some stop words using the `stopwords.txt` file and rebuilt my indexes. Everything looks fine here, I can see that those stop words are no longer indexed:

[image]

All that being said **Query Time** is my issue.

Firstly, here is my `text_general` field type config on `managed-schema`:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Since the `StopFilterFactory` is there on both **Index and Query time** I'm wondering why queries with stop words are keeping those words during execution.

Let's say I'm quering `Designed for you`.

Since `for` is a stopword my query should really be `Designed you`.

Here is the code handling the query:

```
var keywordsFilter = PredicateBuilder.True<UnifiedSearchResultItemWithLocalDatasource>();
            foreach (var keyword in keywords)
            {
                var keywordFilter = PredicateBuilder.False<UnifiedSearchResultItemWithLocalDatasource>();
                keywordFilter = keywordFilter.Or(item => item.UnifiedTitle.Like(keyword, 0.8f).Boost(8f))
                    .Or(item => item.UnifiedTitle.StartsWith(keyword).Boost(8f))
                    .Or(item => item.UnifiedSiteSection.Like(keyword, 0.8f).Boost(4f))
                    .Or(item => item.UnifiedSiteSection.StartsWith(keyword).Boost(4f))
                    .Or(item => item.UnifiedDescription.Like(keyword, 0.8f).Boost(2f))
                    .Or(item => item.UnifiedDescription.StartsWith(keyword).Boost(2f));

                keywordsFilter = keywordsFilter.And(keywordFilter);
            }
```

And here is the Search log with the generated Solr query:

> 16776 17:32:29 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=((-unifiedtitle_t:("") 
>   unifiedtitle_t:[* TO *]) AND ((((unifiedtitle_t:(designed~0.8))^8 OR
>   (unifiedtitle_t:(designed*))^8 OR
>   (unifiedsitesection_t:(designed~0.8))^4 OR
>   (unifiedsitesection_t:(designed*))^4 OR
>   (unifieddescription_t:(designed~0.8))^2 OR
>   (unifieddescription_t:(designed*))^2) AND
>   **((unifiedtitle_t:(for~0.8))^8 OR (unifiedtitle_t:(for*))^8 OR
>   (unifiedsitesection_t:(for~0.8))^4 OR (unifiedsitesection_t:(for*))^4
>   OR (unifieddescription_t:(for~0.8))^2 OR
>   (unifieddescription_t:(for*))^2))** AND ((unifiedtitle_t:(you~0.8))^8 OR
>   (unifiedtitle_t:(you*))^8 OR (unifiedsitesection_t:(you~0.8))^4 OR
>   (unifiedsitesection_t:(you*))^4 OR (unifieddescription_t:(you~0.8))^2
>   OR
>   (unifieddescription_t:(you*))^2)))&start=0&rows=10&fl=*,score&fq=((_latestversion:(True)
>   AND has_presentation_b:(True)) AND
>   _language:(en))&fq=_indexname:(index_master_index)&facet=true&facet.field=computedarticlecategoryname_s&f.computedarticlecategoryname_s.facet.mincount=0&facet.field=computedresidencetypename_s&f.computedresidencetypename_s.facet.mincount=0&wt=xml

As you guys can see the stopped keyword is still there.

And since the indexing is doing its work properly, I don't have any `for` term indexed. The result is that the above query is always returning `0 results`.

What am I doing wrong guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's a pretty lame suggestion but can you try Reloading the index and try.

Comment: You mean restart the Solr service and/or rebuilding the index? Already did and still the same, thanks anyway.

Comment: No, in the Core Admin there is an option called "Reload". Try that

Comment: Tried that, same results. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query analysis (i.E. filtering stopwords) is done by Solr after a query has been sent. Sitecore's search.log log only logs the queries as they are sent to Solr. It is therefore correct to see your stop words in search.log.

To check how Solr actually analyzes a term, use the very helpful Analysis tool on your 'text_general' field:

```
https://mysolr/solr/#/mycore/analysis
```

The issue likely lies in the way you are combining the keyword predicates. Try running the logged query directly on the Solr UI and remove parts step by step to narrow down the issue.

Additionally, check the following:

- does your dynamicField *_t map to type="text_general" in managed-schema?
- is "for" acutally contained in your stopwords.txt?

Comment: You are totally right Mark, thanks a lot. However, I'm not sure if the ANDs are the issue here. I edited my original query down to `((unifieddescription_t:(for~0.8)))` and tried to run it agains Solr directly. Still, no results.

Comment: Btw here is the parsedString when running in debug mode: `"parsedquery":"unifieddescription_t:for~0",`

Comment: Should the above query behave just like this one (if `for` is a stop word)? 
`unifieddescription_t:(*)`

Comment: Querying for a stop word returns 0 results. I just tested this.

Comment: Alright, so maybe I had wrong expectations related to this subject. So basically if I still want to use stop words I'll have to change my `keyword AND keyword AND keyword` to `keyword OR keyword OR keyword`, otherwise a query with stop words will always have 0 results. Is this assumption right?

Comment: what's the query you are trying in solr? e.g. if you search for "the cat", because "the" is a stopword, it should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more comprehensive Sitecore answer:

1. Find your dynamic field that you wish to query against in the Schema browser
   [image: schema browser]

Note the Dynamic Field and Type

2. Double confirm by viewing the dynamicField definition in managed-schema:
   [image: dynamic field definition]
3. In my case, everything points to the type "text_en". Find it in managed-schema:
   [image: text_en definition]
4. Locate the stopwords definition file
5. Pull down the configset, modify the stopwords file, reupload and then reload the collections

Also, in order to validate the changes:

1. Use the Analysis tool on your collection and be sure to select the TYPE, in my case the Type "text_en":
   [image: validating stop words]

I can see that the ® is removed as I have added it as a stop word.