# Why Solr returns 0 results when querying with stopwords only?

Tags: content-search, solr

Really straightforward question:

**Why does Solr return 0 results when I query using only *for*, which is a stop word on my Solr setup?**

IMO this scenario should behave as a query without any keywords at all, which is returning all legit results as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't fully describe the setup you have, I'm assuming this is a followup to this: [How to apply stop words at Solr query time?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22765/how-to-apply-stop-words-at-solr-query-time)

Basically you're chaining up multiple clauses in an AND boolean query. Once Solr processes that it will remove the stopwords (as you expect).

So you end up with `clause AND clause AND removed-stopword-clause (always FALSE) AND clause`. The result of this will always be 0 results.

This is explained in greater detail here:

> Specifically what is happening is that the query parser passes "of" to the
>   analyzer for the name field, which removes the stopwords, including "of",
>   which results in no term to be queried. A Lucene BooleanQuery with no terms
>   will match... nothing. But then when you add another clause, you have the
>   combination of an empty term, and a specific term, which is equivalent to
>   just using the specific term. Think of a sequence of terms to be ANDed as a
>   set - if a term analyzing to no terms, there are no terms to add to the set
>   of terms to be ANDed.

Source: https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/AND-query-not-working-on-stopwords-as-expected-tp4186817p4186843.html

Comment: Thanks Mark, maybe I had wrong expectations related to this subject. So basically if I still want to use stop words I'll have to change my `keyword AND keyword AND keyword` to `keyword OR keyword OR keyword`, otherwise a query with stop words will always have 0 results. Is this assumption right?

Comment: Yea. Elsewhere in the linked article someone suggests to leave the stopwords IN the index, but filter them at query time. I don't think this would change the situation for you however.